# How wide can a Python bitwise reference be?

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

Theoretical, because I haven't yet found a definitive answe..

In Python, I want to reference a variable of bitwise flags of arbitrary length, such as checking

```
if (bvar & 1<<135):
    pass
```

Can this be handled under the covers, or do I need to use special typing or some other explicit mechanism?

Comment: Python integers are arbitrary length, it handles this automatically.

Comment: However, you might want to use the [`bitarray`](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) library to make the code cleaner.